# CSS won't load in Firefox, IE, Edge, but works fine in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, microsoft-edge

I'm developing a site and have been using Chrome for testing. When I test the site in multiple browsers, I have no problem viewing the site in my local development environment. Today, I'm ready to launch the site. I transfer my files, pull the file up online, and find that my CSS only works in Chrome, not in other browsers. Why?

Firefox error message: "Style sheet could not be loaded."

Explorer error message: (evidently no message)

Code for linking to the CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/style.php">
```

There's nothing in particular that makes this stylesheet different from any other I've ever made, but I am using a hosting plan I've not used before.

Comment: `style.php` is a css file?

Comment: is it normal that your style sheet is .php?

Comment: @achref I generate dynamic CSS files with PHP all the time. Is that not normal? Like I say, chrome reads it just fine, and all the other browsers do too in my local environment.

Comment: @Truth Are you sure your local environment is not reading cached files or data from some other location or file type?

Comment: What are the HTTP response headers served with the stylesheet? Is the page in quirks mode?

Comment: @TylerH I don't see how it could be. I've cleared my browser history a dozen times in development. This page does reference two stylesheets, but both use the same code and the external environment doesn't seem to be drawing on either of them. When I alter these sheets, my local webpage is altered, so obviously they're affecting the page locally. It's not like I have a totally different sheet I've forgotten to load or something, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @Truth You should be seeing 406 HTTP response codes on every browser with a PHP file as your stylesheet. I'm surprised Chrome is accepting it honestly.

Comment: @TylerH - I've been doing it for years and have used it on dozens of sites. This is the first problem I've ever had. Now that you mention it, I do get some warnings about mime types now and then, but I've just brushed them off because there's never been a problem before.

Comment: @Truth can we see the contents of your style.php file? And the file path of the style.php file along with the path of your html file that is calling it? Not being condescending, just want to rule everything out.

Comment: @TylerH - Oh, not condescending at all! I'm the one begging for answers. Give me a few minutes though. I'm trying to put up some pure CSS and see if that resolves it.

Comment: @TylerH - I guess I'm a monkey's uncle. Pure CSS works. I'm not sure what's different about this hosting environment that it's giving me a problem when nothing else does, but a solution is a solution! Thanks fellas!

Comment: @Truth Interesting, I will update my answer with a response relevant to that info.

Comment: For what it's worth: I searched for ‘file extension’ all over https://whatwg.org/html, and the only mention was relating to uploading and downloading files, to show the user a proper save as/open window.

Comment: I used to serve PHP scripts as text/css years ago as well and can attest that it works. In fact, I just spent the last 10 minutes throwing together a [demo](https://dev.novalistic.com/demos/dynamic_css.php) to show that it indeed still works for me. This sounds like either a misconfigured script or a misconfigured or restrictive server. We really need to see your script and the HTTP response it's sending out, at least the bits that matter (how it's sending the Content-Type header, whether there are any errors, etc).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While the .php file extension for `type="text/css"` import declaration is not problematic, it's best to make sure you don't have any actual PHP in the file. It's also possible that your new hosting provider could also require that CSS files use the .css extension for reasons of security, policy, etc.

Typically when browsers encounter unacceptable files in a scenario like this, they error out with a 406 response code. It's odd that Chrome is not giving you a problem while other browsers are.

At any rate, switching to a pure CSS file with a .css extension should make all the browsers happy, because we *know* that method works in every browser.

Comment: I've found PHP to be very useful for making stylesheets: you can set a color at the top of the page, and when you decide to change it, you change the variable one time instead of 50. Tired of calculating width=width-padding? Make the sheet do it for you. Want to let your user change his page features? He can save some variables and PHP can pull them later. I thought everyone was doing it.

Comment: @Truth It might be common in PHP (I have avoided it like the plague since 2008 or 2009 as much as possible), but these days people write CSS code in a pre-processor like Sass, which provides such similar things like variables, loops, etc. and then compiles into more verbose CSS before being processed by the web browser. Of course, these days, vanilla CSS supports variables and other powerful tools!

Comment: @TylerH - Could you illuminate me on any particular security threat this might pose? I don't doubt that the new hosting environment has banned this practice for a security reason, but I wouldn't know how to exploit it. If it is a security problem, I need to make sure I go back and lock some doors.

Comment: @Truth I'm not personally versed in security threats (I'm not an independent web dev and have never worked in a security team), but I do know the subject is typically referred to as CSS injection. If you have written pure CSS in your previous PHP files then you are probably safe. If it is a security restriction, it is to cover the hosting provider's tail rather than their customers' tails, would be my bet.